# Store decimal number in contract and then read it back

Tags: solidity

I am trying to store a decimal number in a smart contract struct which represent the price of an item.

The field in the struct is `uint` and I want to store values like `0.001` which is the cost in ether. When I read the cost value I get a BigNumber similar to this:

`BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }`

How can I read the value 0.0001 from the frontend?

Comment: use ufixed128x19 datatype in solidity 
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

Comment: It doesn't work. UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ufixed datatypes are not supported yet. See the warning notice in [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html).

But you can save the number insolidity multiplied by `10**decimals`, where `decimals` is the number of decimal points you want to use. When you retrieve the value in at the front end you just need to divide the returned number by `10**decimals`.

I hope this helps.